# Is there a way to output an IP address dynamically assigned in Vagrant

Tags: vagrant, dynamic-ip

I have Vagrantfile that assigns the `public_network` IP address dynamically, like so:

```
  # Grab the name of the default interface
  $default_network_interface = `ip route | awk '/^default/ {printf "%s", $5; exit 0}'`
  config.vm.network "public_network", bridge: "#$default_network_interface",
    use_dhcp_assigned_default_route: true
```

Tell me please, is there a way I can output the IP address the DHCP server assigns to the virtual machine? I want to use the IP address later on in my other provisioning activities.

Thanks in advance.